# Issue when mat-sidenav-container and mat-sidenav in different components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have separated out mat-sidenav-container and mat-sidenav into two different components. When I have my sidenav in two components like this, the mode "side" is not working anymore. The mode switch to "over".
When I have all in the same component, it's working.

```
<app-layout>
 <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-layout>
```

**app-layout** contains **mat-sidenav-container** component and
**app-sidenav** contains **mat-sidenav** component

During runtime,

```
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

gets wrapped by mat-sidenav-content.

Comment: Duplicate of [Angular Material Sidenav inside custom component doesn't render right sidenav properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290045/angular-material-sidenav-inside-custom-component-doesnt-render-right-sidenav-pr)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping `<mat-drawer>` or `<mat-sidenav>` in a custom component is not currently supported and won't work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48308330/9226213.